# How to make Jasmine 5 create a HTML report?

Tags: jasmine

I am trying to find a way to run a Jasmine 5 test, and get a meaningful HTML report out of it. I was looking at the reporters in Karma, but since i am using Jasmine for API testing, I have no use for my tests running in a browser. As such I would like to avoid the extra complexity if possible.

I can see in the [jasmine node setup guide](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html) that it is possible to set a reporter but I can't seem to find a list of included Jasmine reporters. I do see something that looks like a html reporter in the [codebase](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/tree/main/src/html).

How can I confugire Jasmine to output some kind of persistent report, preferably in HTML?